# How to extend multiple lines at once ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, arcgis-10.0, line

I have 1700 cross sections lines in a shapefile that are too short and I need to extend all of them about 100-200ft. I don't really want to go click on each line vertex and extend each one individually or redraw 1700 lines to be longer. How can I lengthen a bunch of lines to my desired length at once?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We use a Focused question/Best answer model here. Coding questions need to include code.  Your title specifies ArcMap, but the tags include QGIS and ArcGIS 10.0 (which is long retired).  What is the actual release you are using?  What have you tried?

Comment: Look at the geoprocessing tool Extend Lines.  You are extending them a significant distance so you may need to check and refine the results.

Answer (score 0):

Use River bathimetry Toolkit addon and chose Thalweg Tool under Bank/Centerline Tool